# Dataframe - найти самое большое число в строке нескольких столбцов

Tags: python

Как в каждой строке конкретных столбцов найти самое большое число? Образно:`max(res['c1'], res['c2'])`

```
        c1       c2       c3   (результат для макс. с1 и с2:)

0       24       17       19         24
1        9       16       2          16
2       20      201       34         201
3       24       16       83         24
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что-то такое:

```py
df['max_c1_c2'] = df[['c1','c2']].max(axis=1)
```

Старайтесь мыслить *векторно*, тут только `axis` бывает сложно угадать.

Ну и ещё вот эти двойные квадратные скобки `df[['c1','c2']]` тут тоже нужно привыкнуть. Когда мы обращаемся не к одному столбцу, а сразу к нескольким, то нужно передать список столбцов и получается вот такая штука.